# Sharepoint Foundation License Costs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing, sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

This question keeps getting asked however I could never get a straight answer. So I'm asking it clearer:

If I have Windows 2008 R2 Web edition and I'm using Sharepoint Foundation Server on Sql Server 2008 R2 Express edition do I need any further licenses other than what I paid for Windows Server to allow unauthenticated users to view the sharepoint website?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, please reopen

Comment: Check the answers, they essentially boil down to "It depends"

Comment: @TheLQ This is why I spelled out what envrionment and products I will be using, so there won't be any "it depends" comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SharePoint Foundation is free if you own the Windows Web edition server license.  No SharePoint server or CAL licenses are required.
- SQL Express does not require SQL server licenses or CAL's.
- Web Edition requires no Windows CAL's if used for Internet users.
- SharePoint+SQL Express+Windows Web must run on a single server to qualify.

According this page. http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-web-server.aspx

I would call MS licencing and ask anyway if I were you. http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/contact-us.aspx

Comment: Tried that. Even those guys don't know.